# VS code operator mono light does not seem to support ligatures

Tags: visual-studio-code, ligature

After along wait I got the operator mono font, this is the setting I have in my settings file in VS code.

```
{
    "editor.fontFamily": "Operator Mono Light",
    "editor.fontSize": 14,
    "editor.fontLigatures": true,
}
```

However ligatures does not seem to work, do I need to set an additional setting.

Answer (score 5):

I created a project that will add custom ligatures directly to the Operator Mono font. It even includes italic ligatures.

https://github.com/kiliman/operator-mono-lig

Answer (score 0):

Operator mono does not have coding ligatures.  Try Fira Code.

Answer (score 0):

By default,  operator mono doesn't have the font ligatures. You should try out Operator Mono Lig Book. I'm currently using it and it's really cool.

User settings (Linux Ubuntu) for vs code will look something like this:

```
  "editor.fontFamily": "operator mono lig book",
```